# Confusion about the parameter in tf.estimator.Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.x

So I am using

```
tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn, model_dir=None, config=None, params=None, warm_start_from=None
)
```

and I am confused about the parameter `params`.

I know it's a `dict` and according to some example code, I assume that `params` is some like:

```
params = {"batch_size":128,
          "hidden_layer": 3
}
```

but according to the official page, `params` is dict of hyper parameters that will be passed into model_fn. Keys are names of parameters, values are basic python types ([offical page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#args)). So the value should be python types like int64, float64?

Please give me a clear explanation. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Further down the [docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/blob/r2.3/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py#L89):

> The `params` argument contains hyperparameters. It is passed to the
> `model_fn`, if the `model_fn` has a parameter named "params", and to the input
> functions in the same manner. `Estimator` only passes params along, it does
> not inspect it. The structure of `params` is therefore entirely up to the
> developer.

In other words, what's appropriate is what *you* decide is appropriate. If your model loads weights, it could be string path to the weights file: `weights_path = "model.h5"`. Float for dropout rate, between `0.` and `1.`. Like so:

```py
def model_fn(params):
    ...
    x = Dense(params['units'])(x)
    x = Dropout(params['dropout'])(x)
    ...
    model.load_weights(params['weights_path'])
    return model
```

TF checks if `model_fn` has `params` argument [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/blob/r2.3/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py#L1120), and passes it in accordingly. `model_fn` can have any other args as well.